# xerox workcenter 3215 scanner isn't recognized on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, scanner, xerox

I've recently upgraded to 18.04, and my scanner (xerox workcenter 3215) isn't recognized anymore.  I've tried to find a driver without luck, and I 
have very little idea what to do next.

Comment: Also a problem on Disco (19.04). I can print, just can't scan.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane_Troubleshooting If I can get it to work, (I think the symlink trick will work) I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the manufacturer's website for the latest drivers.

[Link to Xerox WorkCenter 3215 Scanner Drivers for Linux OS](https://www.support.xerox.com/support/workcentre-3215/downloads/enus.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en)

The site says they support up to Ubuntu **10.04** but you shared that you weren't even able to find *any* drivers, so give this a try first.

Comment: thanks, though I thought it was clear that the scanner did work before the upgrade, therefore an 8 year old driver doesn't really help...

Comment: have you managed to figure this out? I'm also interested in finding a solution...

Comment: Reszli - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Managed by manually uninstalling by:

```
cd uld
```

then:

```
sudo sh uninstall.sh
```

then:

```
sudo sh install.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I got this to work on 19.04.

First I ran this:

`SANE_DLL_DEBUG=5 scanimage -L`

Which will load through all the backends and list a lot of debugging messages. The xerox 3215 driver is **smfp**.

`[dll] load: dlopen()ing '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-smfp.so.1'`

`[dll] load: dlopen() failed (libusb-0.1.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)`

Well, it looks like we have a dependency problem. Unstall libusb-0.1-4.

`sudo apt install libusb-0.1-4`

And then test:

`scanimage -L`

`device 'smfp:usb;0924;42db;K6B992099' is a XEROX WorkCentre 3215 on USB Scanner`

**Success!**

If you can't get the smfp backend to load, remember that Ubuntu 17+ changed how SANE looks for backends.  You can use the symlink line to ensure the xerox "smfp" backend (the proprietary one) is being loaded but this may not be necessary.

`sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib/sane/libsane-smfp* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane`

I also added myself to the `lp` group. This may also not be necessary.